# What is correct way to override POST data in a Django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, overriding, updating

Let's say that we have a view *ItemAdmin* and a form *ItemAdminForm*.  On this admin page, I want to be able to click a button to notify all users that have signed up to know when an item has become available for download.  I have a model for this as follows:

```
class PreregisteredUser(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='preregistered_users')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='preregistrations')
    date_registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = 'item', 'user'
```

On submit, I want the logic to be something like the following:

1. If notify_users was clicked, find all preregistered users who have not yet been notified.
2. Notify these users.
3. Update these users as having been notified.

So in the *save* method of the form, I do (1) and (2).  For (3) I use:

```
PreregisteredUser.objects.filter(item=item).update(notified=True)
```

Problem is, when the page reloads, all the users are still marked as not having been notified.  So I don't know if this is just not taking effect, or maybe it is taking effect, but because the boxes were not manually checked, it's overwriting the changes I'm trying to make with the update.

So the question is, how do I override the inputs of the form so that the update takes effect?  Does this belong somewhere else beside the *save* method?  Does this require use of *post_save*?  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use `pre_save()` and add your logic there.  That way, when your page loads, it's loading the data you manipulated.